# Getting these responsive square divs to sit next to each other

Tags: html, css, grid, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I'm working on a site that is going to look like this:

[image: Site]

However, I am having some trouble getting the divs on the third row not to move when I resize the window. To give you an idea of what i'm talking about, here are pictures...

At normal window size:
[image]

When I make the window smaller:

[image]

How can I make it so that the two divs stay the same as they are in the first picture and don't change position when i adjust the window size. Also, is there any way I can make the text resize along with the div?

Here is my code so far:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Trend Sans 004'; /*a name to be used later*/
    src: url('fonts/Trend Sans W00 Four.ttf'); /*URL to font*/
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Utopia Regular'; /*a name to be used later*/
    src: url('fonts/utopia-regular.ttf'); /*URL to font*/
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Trend Sans 001'; /*a name to be used later*/
    src: url('fonts/Trend Sans W00 One.ttf'); /*URL to font*/
}




/*
* Skeleton V2.0.4
* Copyright 2014, Dave Gamache
* www.getskeleton.com
* Free to use under the MIT license.
* http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
* 12/29/2014
*/


/* Table of contents
––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
- Grid
- Base Styles
- Typography
- Links
- Buttons
- Forms
- Lists
- Code
- Tables
- Spacing
- Utilities
- Clearing
- Media Queries
*/


/* Grid
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
.column,
.columns {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box; }

/* For devices larger than 400px */
@media (min-width: 400px) {
  .container {
    width: 85%;
    padding: 0; }
}

/* For devices larger than 550px */
@media (min-width: 550px) {
  .container {
    width: 80%; }
  .column,
  .columns {
    margin-left: 4%; }
  .column:first-child,
  .columns:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
    }

  .one.column,
  .one.columns                    { width: 4.66666666667%; }
  .two.columns                    { width: 13.3333333333%; }
  .three.columns                  { width: 22%;            }
  .four.columns                   { width: 30.6666666667%; }
  .five.columns                   { width: 39.3333333333%; }
  .six.columns                    { width: 48%;            }
  .seven.columns                  { width: 56.6666666667%; }
  .eight.columns                  { width: 65.3333333333%; }
  .nine.columns                   { width: 74.0%;          }
  .ten.columns                    { width: 82.6666666667%; }
  .eleven.columns                 { width: 91.3333333333%; }
  .twelve.columns                 { width: 100%; margin-left: 0; }

  .one-third.column               { width: 30.6666666667%; }
  .two-thirds.column              { width: 65.3333333333%; }

  .one-half.column                { width: 48%; }

  /* Offsets */
  .offset-by-one.column,
  .offset-by-one.columns          { margin-left: 8.66666666667%; }
  .offset-by-two.column,
  .offset-by-two.columns          { margin-left: 17.3333333333%; }
  .offset-by-three.column,
  .offset-by-three.columns        { margin-left: 26%;            }
  .offset-by-four.column,
  .offset-by-four.columns         { margin-left: 34.6666666667%; }
  .offset-by-five.column,
  .offset-by-five.columns         { margin-left: 43.3333333333%; }
  .offset-by-six.column,
  .offset-by-six.columns          { margin-left: 52%;            }
  .offset-by-seven.column,
  .offset-by-seven.columns        { margin-left: 60.6666666667%; }
  .offset-by-eight.column,
  .offset-by-eight.columns        { margin-left: 69.3333333333%; }
  .offset-by-nine.column,
  .offset-by-nine.columns         { margin-left: 78.0%;          }
  .offset-by-ten.column,
  .offset-by-ten.columns          { margin-left: 86.6666666667%; }
  .offset-by-eleven.column,
  .offset-by-eleven.columns       { margin-left: 95.3333333333%; }

  .offset-by-one-third.column,
  .offset-by-one-third.columns    { margin-left: 34.6666666667%; }
  .offset-by-two-thirds.column,
  .offset-by-two-thirds.columns   { margin-left: 69.3333333333%; }

  .offset-by-one-half.column,
  .offset-by-one-half.columns     { margin-left: 52%; }

}


/* Base Styles
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
/* NOTE
html is set to 62.5% so that all the REM measurements throughout Skeleton
are based on 10px sizing. So basically 1.5rem = 15px :) */
html {
  font-size: 62.5%; }
body {
background-color:#C8D7DC;
}


/* Typography
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  font-weight: 300; }
h1 { font-size: 4.0rem; line-height: 1.2;  letter-spacing: -.1rem;}
h2 { font-size: 3.6rem; line-height: 1.25; letter-spacing: -.1rem; }
h3 { font-size: 3.0rem; line-height: 1.3;  letter-spacing: -.1rem; }
h4 { font-size: 2.4rem; line-height: 1.35; letter-spacing: -.08rem; }
h5 { font-size: 1.8rem; line-height: 1.5;  letter-spacing: -.05rem; }
h6 { font-size: 1.5rem; line-height: 1.6;  letter-spacing: 0; }

/* Larger than phablet */
@media (min-width: 550px) {
  h1 { font-size: 5.0rem; }
  h2 { font-size: 4.2rem; }
  h3 { font-size: 3.6rem; }
  h4 { font-size: 3.0rem; }
  h5 { font-size: 2.4rem; }
  h6 { font-size: 1.5rem; }
}

p {
  margin-top: 0; }





/* Buttons
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
.button,
button,
input[type="submit"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="button"] {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 38px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  color: #555;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 38px;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
.button:hover,
button:hover,
input[type="submit"]:hover,
input[type="reset"]:hover,
input[type="button"]:hover,
.button:focus,
button:focus,
input[type="submit"]:focus,
input[type="reset"]:focus,
input[type="button"]:focus {
  color: #333;
  border-color: #888;
  outline: 0; }
.button.button-primary,
button.button-primary,
input[type="submit"].button-primary,
input[type="reset"].button-primary,
input[type="button"].button-primary {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #33C3F0;
  border-color: #33C3F0; }
.button.button-primary:hover,
button.button-primary:hover,
input[type="submit"].button-primary:hover,
input[type="reset"].button-primary:hover,
input[type="button"].button-primary:hover,
.button.button-primary:focus,
button.button-primary:focus,
input[type="submit"].button-primary:focus,
input[type="reset"].button-primary:focus,
input[type="button"].button-primary:focus {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #1EAEDB;
  border-color: #1EAEDB; }


/* Forms
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
input[type="email"],
input[type="number"],
input[type="search"],
input[type="text"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="url"],
input[type="password"],
textarea,
select {
  height: 38px;
  padding: 6px 10px; /* The 6px vertically centers text on FF, ignored by Webkit */
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #D1D1D1;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: none;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
/* Removes awkward default styles on some inputs for iOS */
input[type="email"],
input[type="number"],
input[type="search"],
input[type="text"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="url"],
input[type="password"],
textarea {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none; }
textarea {
  min-height: 65px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 6px; }
input[type="email"]:focus,
input[type="number"]:focus,
input[type="search"]:focus,
input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="tel"]:focus,
input[type="url"]:focus,
input[type="password"]:focus,
textarea:focus,
select:focus {
  border: 1px solid #33C3F0;
  outline: 0; }
label,
legend {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  font-weight: 600; }
fieldset {
  padding: 0;
  border-width: 0; }
input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  display: inline; }
label > .label-body {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: .5rem;
  font-weight: normal; }


/* Lists
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
ul {
  list-style: circle inside; }
ol {
  list-style: decimal inside; }
ol, ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0; }
ul ul,
ul ol,
ol ol,
ol ul {
  margin: 1.5rem 0 1.5rem 3rem;
  font-size: 90%; }
li {
  margin-bottom: 1rem; }


/* Code
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
code {
  padding: .2rem .5rem;
  margin: 0 .2rem;
  font-size: 90%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #F1F1F1;
  border: 1px solid #E1E1E1;
  border-radius: 4px; }
pre > code {
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  white-space: pre; }


/* Tables
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
th,
td {
  padding: 12px 15px;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E1E1E1; }
th:first-child,
td:first-child {
  padding-left: 0; }
th:last-child,
td:last-child {
  padding-right: 0; }


/* Spacing
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
button,
.button {
  margin-bottom: 1rem; }
input,
textarea,
select,
fieldset {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem; }
pre,
blockquote,
dl,
figure,
table,
p,
ul,
ol,
form {
  margin-bottom: 2.5rem; }


/* Utilities
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
.u-full-width {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
.u-max-full-width {
  max-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
.u-pull-right {
  float: right; }
.u-pull-left {
  float: left; }


/* Misc
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */



/* Clearing
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

/* Self Clearing Goodness */
.container:after,
.row:after,
.u-cf {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both; }


/* Media Queries
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
/*
Note: The best way to structure the use of media queries is to create the queries
near the relevant code. For example, if you wanted to change the styles for buttons
on small devices, paste the mobile query code up in the buttons section and style it
there.
*/


/* Larger than mobile */
@media (min-width: 400px) {}

/* Larger than phablet (also point when grid becomes active) */
@media (min-width: 550px) {}

/* Larger than tablet */
@media (min-width: 750px) {}

/* Larger than desktop */
@media (min-width: 1000px) {}

/* Larger than Desktop HD */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {}


/* Header
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

#header {
font-size:10vw;
margin-top:5%;
text-align: center;
font-family:'Trend Sans 004';
color: #806239;
}


/* Row 1
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

#row1 {
font-family:'Trend Sans 001';
color:#806239;
border: 2px #806239 solid;
margin-top:2%;
padding:1%;
font-size:2vw;
white-space: nowrap;
}

#row1 a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#806239;
}

#row1 a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#806239;
}

#row1 a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#806239;
}

#row1 a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#806239;
}


#row1 ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

#row1 li {
    display: inline;
    
}

#row1 li {
    display: inline;
}

#kjn {
padding-right:25%;
padding-left:25%;
}



/* Row 3
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

#row3 {
background-color:#806239;
font-family:'Utopia Regular';
margin-top:2%;
text-align:center;
color: white;
padding:5%;
}

#mail {
font-family:'Trend Sans 001';
letter-spacing:2px;
font-size:1.8vw;
}

#first {
margin-top:-5%;
font-size:1.5vw;
letter-spacing:.4px;
}





/* Box Row
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

#boxRow {
font-family:'Utopia Regular';
margin-top:2%;
}

#boxRowImg1 {
background-image: url("images/interior.png");
background-color:grey;
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-size: cover;
font-family:'Utopia Regular';
width: 48%;
height: 0;
padding-bottom: 48%;
}


#boxRowTxt {
font-family:'Utopia Regular';
box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 3px #806239 inset;
width: 48%;
color:#806239;
position:relative;
height: 0;
padding-bottom: 48%;
}

#boxRowTxt h5 {
font-family:'Trend Sans 001';

font-size:3vw;
}

#boxRowTxt p {
margin-top:-20px;
color:#806239;
font-size:10px;
}

#boxRowTxt hr {
height:1px;
width:40%;
background-color:#806239;
border-width:0px;
}

#aa {
padding-top:20px;
padding-bottom:20px;
padding-left:10%;
padding-right:10%;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
}



/* hr
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

#row5 hr {
height:2px;
width:100%;
background-color:#806239;
border-width:0px;
margin-top:3%;
}

/* Row 6
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

#row6 {
font-family:'Trend Sans 001';
margin-top:.5%;
margin-bottom:1.5%;
font-size:1.3vw;
color:#806239;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <!-- Basic Page Needs
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Cupid's Cafe & Bakery</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Cupid's Cafe & Bakery">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <!-- Mobile Specific Metas
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- FONT
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  

  <!-- CSS
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Cupids.css">
  

  <!-- Favicon
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">

</head>
<body>

  <!-- Primary Page Layout
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <div class="container">
  
  <div class="row">
  <div class="twelve columns" id="header">
  Cupid's
  </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
  <div class="twelve columns" id="row1">
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#menu">Menu</a></li>
  <li><a id="kjn" href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="row" id="boxRow">
  <div class="six columns" id="boxRowImg1" >
  </div>
  <div class="six columns" id="boxRowTxt" >
  <div id="aa">
  <h5>The Cafe</h5></br>
  <p>Like a home away from home, our secluded cafe is the perfect place to relax, work, or settle in with a good book. Make sure to try one of our delicious lunch options or expertly brewed hot drinks. </p>
  <hr align="left" >
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  
   
  <div class="row">
  <div class="twelve columns" id="row5">
  <hr width="100%">
  </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
  <div class="twelve columns" id="row6">
  copyright 2016, emily baker
  </div>
  </div>
  
    
  </div>

<!-- End Document
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful about this media query :

```
@media (min-width: 550px)
.column, .columns {
    margin-left: 4%;
}
```

This query add a margin-left when the size of the window is larger than 550px. You have to adapt it to fix your issue ;)

Another solution could be to change the layout when you're with a very small width. For example, putting the two div in a 100% width one above the other.

You can do that with a media query.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, it seems like the divs snap together when the window hits ~550px wide. More likely than not, its skeleton doing that for you, so I'd look for a media query which changes padding or margin.

As for your second question, yes, you can change the size of the text as the window changes sizes, but whether or not that is something you want for your users is another question. You can look into using rem or percentages for the `font-size` property of that element.